# omnet++ M/M/1 queue length

Tags: lambda, queue, omnet++

I try to simulate MM1 queue classic with infinite queue, exponential inter-arrival and service rate.
My problem is when a calculate through statistics the average length of queue.
Theoretically, using arrival rate lambda = 1/20 and service rate mu = 1/5, i should experiment a mean queue value of 1/6 given that rho = lambda/mu = 1/4 and E[number of users in queue] = rho^2/(1-rho) = 1/6.
My simulation of 5000s of sim-time-limit give to me a value of 1/2.
I don't understand why, because all other statistics (response time,waiting time,ecc.) are right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: OMNeT++-s Queue module in the queueinglib example emits the queueLegnt signal with the number of jobs inside the actual queue (i.e. it does NOT include the job that is under servicing). The average of this number is NOT the same as the average of Jobs in the block (which includes also the job under servicing).